# Export API Response to CSV using RUBY

Tags: ruby, arrays, api, rest, csv

I am trying to make a restful API GET request and output the results to a csv file. The response I receive doesn't appear to be comma delimited, sample below:

> ��"Status"    "id"    "Language"  "Created At"    "Updated At"    "IP
>   Address"  "Location"  "Username"  "GET Variables" "Referrer"  "Number of
>   Saves"    "Weighted Score"    "Completion Time"   "Invite Code"   "Invite
>   Email"    "Invite Name"   "Collector" "Collector: company_name"   "First, we
>   would like you ... | Restaurant Name"

I read on the CSV gem docs this line of code, which works:

> CSV.open("./File.csv", "wb") do |csv|
>
> ```
>     csv << ["row","of","data"]
>   end
> ```

However, I need to put the actual response I am receiving from my API call to the csv file. I tried this, which I know is bad but I was just trying to get something to work:

> list = [ ]
>
> list << request.body
>
> ```
> list.each do |x|
>   CSV.open("./File.csv", "w") do |csv|
>     csv << [x]
>   end
> end
> ```

The above converts my File.csv to a text encoded file and puts a # symbol between each character in the file. The format is far from what it needs to be.

Any suggestions? Thanks ahead of time for the help.

Edit-

This is the full raw response.body of the API Get request:

> > ��"Status"  "id"    "Language"  "Created At"    "Updated At"    "IP Address"    "Location"  "Username"  "GET Variables" "Referrer"  "Number of
> >     Saves"    "Weighted Score"    "Completion Time"   "Invite Code"   "Invite
> >     Email"    "Invite Name"   "Collector" "Collector: company_name"   "First, we
> >     would like you ... | Restaurant Name" "First, we would like you ... |
> >     Address"  "First, we would like you ... | Day of the Week and Date of
> >     Visit"    "First, we would like you ... | Time of Visit"  "First, we would
> >     like you ... | Name of Host"  "First, we would like you ... | Name of
> >     Server"   "For each of the following... | Food Quality"   "For each of the
> >     following... | Food Selection"    "For each of the following... | Food
> >     Presentation" "For each of the following... | Healthy Options"    "For
> >     each of the following... | Overall"   "Please provide any additional
> >     comments or thoughts..."  "We would now like to know... | Interior
> >     Decor"    "We would now like to know... | Outside Decor"  "We would now
> >     like to know... | Cleanliness"    "We would now like to know... |
> >     Temperature"  "We would now like to know... | Comfortable Seating"    "We
> >     would now like to know... | Overall Environment"  "Please provide any
> >     additional comments or thoughts..."   "Considering all factors, please
> >     select the respons..."    "Finally, we would like to know if you have any
> >     ove..." "Incomplete"  "19424002"  "en"    "2013/07/18 4:54:18
> >     PM"   "2013/07/18 4:54:27 PM" "173.227.104.54"    "United
> >     States"   "-services-marketing"   "lang=en&_previewpage=7&TEST_DATA=&preview=1"   ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "location"  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
> >     "Complete"    "19424356"  "en"    "2013/07/18 4:57:37 PM" "2013/07/18 4:58:16
> >     PM"   "173.227.104.54"    "United
> >     States"   "-services-marketing"   "TEST_DATA="    "http://fluidsurveys.com/account/surveys/228169/edit/"  ""  "12.0"  "00:00:36"  ""  ""  ""  ""  "location"  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "Very
> >     Dissatisfied" "Very Dissatisfied" "Very Dissatisfied" "Very
> >     Dissatisfied" "Very Dissatisfied" ""  "Very Dissatisfied" "Very
> >     Dissatisfied" "Very Dissatisfied" "Very Dissatisfied" "Very
> >     Dissatisfied" "Very Dissatisfied" ""  "Very Satisfied"    ""
> >     "Incomplete"  "19424569"  "en"    "2013/07/18 4:59:16 PM" "2013/07/18
> >     4:59:47 PM"   "173.227.104.54"    "United
> >     States"   "-services-marketing"   "TEST_DATA="    "link"  ""  "11.0"  "00:00:27"  ""  ""  ""  ""  "location"  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "Very
> >     Dissatisfied" "Very Dissatisfied" "Very Dissatisfied" "Very
> >     Dissatisfied" "Very Dissatisfied" ""  "Very Dissatisfied" "Very
> >     Dissatisfied" "Very Dissatisfied" "Very Dissatisfied" "Very
> >     Dissatisfied" "Very Dissatisfied" ""  ""  ""
> >     "Complete"    "19424722"  "en"    "2013/07/18 5:01:01 PM" "2013/07/18 5:01:22
> >     PM"   "173.227.104.54"    "United
> >     States"   "-services-marketing"   "TEST_DATA="    "http://fluidsurveys.com/account/surveys/228169/edit/"  ""  "12.0"  "00:00:19"  ""  ""  ""  ""  "location"  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "Very
> >     Dissatisfied" "Very Dissatisfied" "Very Dissatisfied" "Very
> >     Dissatisfied" "Very Dissatisfied" ""  "Very Dissatisfied" "Very
> >     Dissatisfied" "Very Dissatisfied" "Very Dissatisfied" "Very
> >     Dissatisfied" "Very Dissatisfied" ""  "Very Satisfied"    ""
> >     "Complete"    "19426165"  "en"    "2013/07/18 5:15:38 PM" "2013/07/18 5:16:53
> >     PM"   "173.227.104.54"    "United
> >     States"   "-services-marketing"   "code=qfstk2frwh"   "link"  ""  "38.0"  "00:01:12"  "qfstk2frwh"    "car@email.com" "dene"  ""  "location"  "DOnato's
> >     " "university"    "7/18/2013" "12:15" "location"  "Self"  "Very
> >     Dissatisfied" "Very Dissatisfied" "Very Dissatisfied" "Very
> >     Dissatisfied" "Very Dissatisfied" "This pizza tastes like
> >     cardboard"    "Very Satisfied"    "Very Satisfied"    "Very Satisfied"    "Very
> >     Satisfied"    "Very Satisfied"    "Very Satisfied"    "best office
> >     ever" "Neutral"   "Like Taziki's better"
> >     "Complete"    "19426705"  "en"    "2013/07/18 5:20:33 PM" "2013/07/18 5:23:19
> >     PM"   "173.227.104.54"    "United
> >     States"   ""  "code=q4wqr9z5vp"   "link"  ""  "44.0"  "00:02:45"  "q4wqr9z5vp"    "jb@email.com"  "jan"   ""  "location"  "Donatos"   "123
> >     location Way" "Thursday, July 18th"   "11:30
> >     a.m." "Rufus" "Lars"  "Satisfied" "Very
> >     Satisfied"    "Neutral"   "Dissatisfied"  "Satisfied" "The pizza was not as
> >     warm as I would have
> >     liked."   "Satisfied" "Satisfied" "Satisfied" "Satisfied" "Satisfied" "Satisfied" "The
> >     restaurant was clean and well-lit."   "Satisfied" "The noise in the
> >     restaurant tends to get a little too loud, which might make diners
> >     uncomfortable." "Complete"    "19426762"  "en"    "2013/07/18 5:20:57
> >     PM"   "2013/07/18 5:22:52 PM" "173.227.104.54"    "United
> >     States"   ""  "code=qnzznmvts8"   "link"  ""  "35.0"  "00:01:53"  "qnzznmvts8"    "js@email.com"  "jon"   ""  "location"  "Chime Steaks"  "14 Chime Street"   "Tuesday 4/2/13"    "4 pm"  "Mr.
> >     Chimerson"    "Sarah Chimesky"    "Very
> >     Satisfied"    "Neutral"   "Satisfied" "Very Satisfied"    "Dissatisfied"  "It
> >     was great."   "Very
> >     Dissatisfied" "Dissatisfied"  "Neutral"   "Satisfied" "Very
> >     Satisfied"    "N/A"   "Great" "Very Satisfied"    "No comments."
> >     "Complete"    "19427035"  "en"    "2013/07/18 5:22:33 PM" "2013/07/18 5:25:42
> >     PM"   "173.227.104.54"    "United
> >     States"   ""  "code=tx5tbsvxkz"   "link"  ""  "46.0"  "00:03:07"  "tx5tbsvxkz"    "jr@email.com"  "jacine"    ""  "location"  "Donatos"   "600
> >     University Place" "7.18.13"   "11:30
> >     am"   "location"  "Jackay"    "Satisfied" "Satisfied" "Satisfied" "Satisfied" "Satisfied" "I
> >     really love FREE food. It tastes so much better than food I have to
> >     pay for.
> >     :)"   "Satisfied" "Satisfied" "Satisfied" "Satisfied" "Satisfied" "Satisfied" "Good
> >     vibes!"   "Satisfied" "I really love FREE food!"
> >     "Complete"    "19427047"  "en"    "2013/07/18 5:22:41 PM" "2013/07/18 5:27:10
> >     PM"   "173.227.104.54"    "United
> >     States"   ""  "code=fczvg3rbrm"   "link"  ""  "36.0"  "00:04:29"  "fczvg3rbrm"    "mam@email.com" "mat"   ""  "location"  "Danatos"   "yesterday" "Mondnesday"    "Before
> >     Time" "location"  "Wife"  "Satisfied" "Neutral"   "Dissatisfied"  "Very
> >     Dissatisfied" "Neutral"   "I just don't like circular pizzas cut into
> >     rectangles. It makes me think they are hiding something, and causes an
> >     eye twitch that will take 3 days to leave."   "Very
> >     Satisfied"    "Satisfied" "Satisfied" "Dissatisfied"  "Dissatisfied"  "Satisfied" "Seats
> >     are too hard. No sound canceling. The floor was clean enough to eat
> >     off of after dropping stuff"  "Satisfied" "Not sure I like the
> >     cafeteria style tables." "Complete"   "19427110"  "en"    "2013/07/18
> >     5:23:10 PM"   "2013/07/18 7:17:40 PM" "173.227.104.54"    "United
> >     States"   ""  "code=pdg733fn5d"   "link"  ""  "44.0"  "00:02:50"  "pdg733fn5d"    "cda@email.com" "clare" ""  "location"  "Denatos"   "123
> >     location Way" "Thursday 7/18/2013"    "11:30
> >     am"   "Clare" "Claire"    "Satisfied" "Satisfied" "Neutral"   "Dissatisfied"  "Neutral"   "I
> >     love the veggie pizza, but it's always gone by the time I get
> >     downstairs!"  "Very Satisfied"    "Very Satisfied"    "Very
> >     Satisfied"    "Dissatisfied"  "Very Satisfied"    "Satisfied" "There's no
> >     better place to eat lunch than Park!" "Satisfied" "I think we should
> >     have McAlister's for family lunch!"
> >     "Complete"    "19428559"  "en"    "2013/07/18 5:35:45 PM" "2013/07/18 5:38:49
> >     PM"   "173.227.104.54"    "United
> >     States"   ""  "code=ncpffmg968"   "link"  ""  "41.0"  "00:03:02"  "ncpffmg968"    "mpolhemus@email.com"   "missy" ""  "location"  "Donatos"   "the
> >     garage"   "thursday"  "12:00
> >     pm"   "me"    "you"   "Satisfied" "Satisfied" "Neutral"   "Neutral"   "Satisfied" "If
> >     someone could serenade me the next time we have pizza, that would be
> >     swell  :)"    "Very Satisfied"    "N/A"   "Very
> >     Satisfied"    "Neutral"   "Neutral"   "Very Satisfied"    ""  "Satisfied" "pizza
> >     was cold- boo" "Complete" "19432903"  "en"    "2013/07/18 6:09:11
> >     PM"   "2013/07/18 6:12:59 PM" "173.227.104.54"    "United
> >     States"   ""  "code=krhb2qw4pr"   "link"  ""  "0" "00:03:47"  "krhb2qw4pr"    "sett@email.com"    "sar"   ""  "location"  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "N/A"   "N/A"   "N/A"   "N/A"   "N/A"   ""  "N/A"   "N/A"   "N/A"   "N/A"   "N/A"   "N/A"   ""  "N/A"   ""
> >     "Complete"    "19435360"  "en"    "2013/07/18 6:30:13 PM" "2013/07/18 6:32:22
> >     PM"   "173.227.104.54"    "United
> >     States"   ""  "code=n8pnrrgmxb"   "link"  ""  "28.0"  "00:02:07"  "n8pnrrgmxb"    "cway@email.com"    "case"  ""  "location"  "Chuck-e-cheese"    "creepersville" "monday
> >     july
> >     15"   "noon"  "Elmo"  "Pigglet"   "Dissatisfied"  "Neutral"   "Dissatisfied"  "Very
> >     Dissatisfied" "Dissatisfied"  ""  "Dissatisfied"  "Neutral"   "Dissatisfied"  "Dissatisfied"  "Neutral"   "Neutral"   ""  "Neutral"   ""
> >     "Complete"    "19445356"  "en"    "2013/07/18 7:57:24 PM" "2013/07/18 8:01:38
> >     PM"   "173.227.104.54"    "United
> >     States"   ""  "code=b5mnsfmgvn"   "link"  ""  "37.0"  "00:04:12"  "b5mnsfmgvn"    "ts@email.com"  "tara"  ""  "location"  "Donatoa"   "Vestavia"  "Thursday"  "12
> >     pm"   "Katie" "Gemr"  "Dissatisfied"  "Dissatisfied"  "Dissatisfied"  "Dissatisfied"  "Dissatisfied"  "Is
> >     this the French spelling for
> >     Donato's?"    "Satisfied" "Satisfied" "Satisfied" "Satisfied" "Satisfied" "Satisfied" "The
> >     environment could be improved by having Gem dance for
> >     customers."   "Neutral"   "More Tazikis, less Donatos"
> >     "Complete"    "19548931"  "en"    "2013/07/19 6:11:47 PM" "2013/07/19 6:13:56
> >     PM"   "173.227.104.54"    "United
> >     States"   ""  "code=nbhzkgh69f"   "link"  ""  "45.0"  "00:02:09"  "nbhzkgh69f"    "ar@email.com"  "aman"  ""  "location"  "Taco Truck"    "500 Ave."  "Friday, 7/5"   "12pm"  "Eio"   "Ben"   "Very
> >     Satisfied"    "Satisfied" "Satisfied" "Neutral"   "Satisfied" "Delicious" "Satisfied" "Satisfied" "Satisfied" "Satisfied" "Satisfied" "Satisfied" "Great" "Very
> >     Satisfied"    "Keep up the good work."

Comment: Give us some more general info on what you want to do - you're trying to solve the problem in a specific way with CSV gem but my experience is that there are other ways. E.g., You want to take the format given at the top and transform it into what format? CSV? Then you want to take that CSV format and transform it again? Into what?

Comment: Sure. The idea is that I'm pulling responses from a online survey to then send out in an email, in a csv format that someone can open in excel to pivot and play with as they wish. I am not partial to the CSV gem and am open to other ways. The goal is simply to take this format and be able to create a readable csv file that I can then open in excel or open office. It will be a tabular report with headers, ideally. Here is the specific API call documentation I am using :
[link](http://docs.fluidsurveys.com/api/surveys.html#getting-responses-as-a-csv)

Comment: Seems that your `list` object is being treated as an array of characters, not an array of strings.  Ask `list` what it is - my guess is `string` not `array`.

Comment: The issue, I assume, is that my array only has one string in it, which is the entire request. I tried using list.split(" ") to split the string to create a larger array, but no luck. I don't think that's the right route to go down anyways, seems like there should be a simpler process. But, to your point, list.class returns Array.

Comment: Well, if it's an array with one string, then try `list[0].split(" ")`

Comment: No dice. The [0] makes sense though. I think there is still an issue with the formatting. That created output to a text encoded file with the following bit of code:

"��""#S#t#a#t#u#s#""# #""#i#d#""# #""#L#a#n#g#u#a#g#e#""# #""#C#r#e#a#t#e#d# #A#t#""

Comment: Try `inspect` on request.body.  Let's see what it's really made of.  Your statement `list << request.body` just creates a one-element array (I should have noticed that earlier).

Comment: That returns a ton of gibberish :

    "\xFF\xFE\"\x00S\x00t\x00a\x00t\x00u\x00s\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00i\x00d\x00\"\x00\t\

The letters at the end of the xOO make up the words that it should be outputting to cells, and \x00\t\x00\ seems to be where the new cell should start.

Comment: Well, that sure looks like an array of characters.  What does `response.body.class` tell you?

Comment: response.body.class returns string.

Comment: Was is supposed to have been JSON?  XML?

Comment: I assume that it shouldn't be. I am using this api call (http://docs.fluidsurveys.com/api/surveys.html#getting-responses-as-a-csv) which "Gets survey responses as CSV". It doesn't state what format it returns, but to post responses from a CSV the content header type must be text/csv. There are other API calls that return JSON that I may be able to parse to CSV easier than this, but this API call seems like it should be a shorter and easier process if I could just figure out how to actually get it to CSV.

Comment: Well, I think that's the root of your problem - the trash in that string.  Once you get that to be an array of strings, you'll be fine creating the csv.  Good luck, sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: No worries, knowing that is a step up from where I was. Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the first line of the csv file to write across..

```
require 'csv'
DOC = 'file.csv'

data = []
data = '"Status" "id" "Language" "Created At" "Updated At" "IP Address" "Location" "Username" "GET Variables" "Referrer" "Number of Saves" "Weighted Score" "Completion Time" "Invite Code" "Invite Email" "Invite Name" "Collector" "Collector: company_name" "First, we would like you ... | Restaurant Name"'
data = data.split('" "')

profile = []
profile[0] = data[0].delete('"')
profile[1] = data[1]
profile[2] = data[2]
profile[3] = data[3]
profile[4] = data[4]
profile[5] = data[5]
profile[6] = data[6]
profile[7] = data[7]
profile[8] = data[8]
profile[9] = data[9]
profile[10] = data[10]
profile[11] = data[11]
profile[12] = data[12]
profile[13] = data[13]
profile[14] = data[14]
profile[15] = data[15]
profile[16] = data[16]
profile[17] = data[17]
profile[18] = data[18]
profile[19] = data[19].delete('"')

CSV.open(DOC, "a") do |data|
data << profile
end
```

By no means is this code dynamic.
Hopefully this will be enough of an example to print to csv. 
If you can, edit your question and put in the RAW output of the "API GET request" you want to convert to csv, and i can help you load your data.

Comment: Good example, I'm still drawing a little bit of a blank as to how I can make it dynamic. I was hoping I could just pass response.body like date = response.body, but no luck. I edited my question with an example of the raw response.body. Does that help?

Comment: Is the output saved in a type of file or format? Or are you going to read this from the console?

Comment: Is there any other way you can view this information. Its possible to parse this but is going to take extra work.

Comment: I am currently reading it from a console- I want the finished product to make it to a csv file. Perhaps I am better off scrapping this entire idea and getting the response as JSON. I assume it will be easier to parse proper JSON to CSV.

Comment: Right now nothing is saved as a .csv. I have copied and pasted everything from a console.

Comment: Can you access this from an irb console? Reason why i ask is because i want to import the data directly from the console to an array using ruby.

Comment: I should be able to access it from an irb console, yes. I suppose we'll find a difference using an irb console that we don't see just passing the response.body to an array in the ruby script?

Comment: You can access the linux terminal using `%x'linux console command'` using that. So we can put it in an array using `data = %x'command'`